# where is Pktextract.exe installed?

Tags: winapi, sxs

I have Visual Studio 2008 and the Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5
installed. I believe that is the latest platform SDK.

I'm trying to build a signed dll to be installed in SxS.
All the tutorials explain to use a tool called pktextract.exe which is part of the SDK, but I can't seem to find the tool. All the other tools such as makecert, mt, makecat exist.

Was pktextract replaced by some other tool in the latest version of the sdk?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VS2008, You can use sn -T to extract the public key token from an assembly or a combination of sn -p and sn -t to extract one from a pfx.

Answer (score 0):

Should be part of the [Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/msdownload/platformsdk/sdkupdate/psdk-full.htm).

Comment: I have the platform sdk installed, and it isn't there

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it from a Visual Studio 2005 installation, there it is found under ...\common\tools\bin

I wonder why it was removed. Maybe MS simply forgot it?